# Is it possible to access DataTable in DataGridView.DataSource so I can use DataTable.Copy()?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I'm attempting to copy DataTable objects so I can store them in a linked list. I had planned to fetch these DataTables from a DataGridView object and use the Copy() method for DataTable.

These DataGridViews contain data retrieved from a MySql database and I am presenting them to the user. If the user wants make a change to the data, I would like the datagridview to reflect the changes (however many the user makes) and then the user can hit a submit button to update changes in the db. The linked list of DataTables serves the purpose of allowing the user to revert some changes that haven't been updated and to display the correct "commit" data on the DataGridView.

Unfortunately, the `DataSource` property for a `DataGridView` holds an object and not `System.Data.DataTable`. Looking at the debugger, the type for the DataSource is object (System.Data.DataTable) and none of the properties allow me to access the entire DataTable directly.

Unless I'm missing something, is there anyway I can access this DataTable directly so I can use DataTable.Copy()? Perhaps some way to make an object enumerable and copy each property of object (System.Data.DataTable) to a DataTable object? I already wrote some code to copy the rows and columns of a DataGridView and I tried storing DataGridViews in a linked list, but that didn't work.

Not much sample code but here's what I had in mind.

```
private LinkedList<DataTable> dataTableChanges = new LinkedList<DataTable>();
public void UserFilterData()
{
    // some code here
    dataTableChanges.AddLast((MyDataGridView.DataSource.Copy());  // DataSource is an obj. Can't call Copy()
}

public void BackButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataTableChanges.Count >= 2 )
    {
        dataTableChanges.RemoveLast();
        MyDataGridView.DataSource = dataTableChanges.Last.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No prior changes to revert to.");
    }
}
```

Comment: make a type cast: `(MyDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).Copy()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridView.DataSource` has `object` type because DataGridView can use different sources: List, DataTable, BindingSource. since you know exactly what is your DataSource, make a type conversion:

```
(MyDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).Copy()
```